# Finite moment for normed sum implies finite moments for the norms of individual terms.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $X'$ are independent and identically distributed elements of a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ with norm $\|\cdot\|^2=\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$,   ($\mathbb{H}$ could be $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm hoping this also holds in infinite dimensions too). If for $\kappa>1$

$$
E\| X - X'\|^\kappa < \infty,
$$
does this imply
$$
E\| X \|^\kappa < \infty?
$$
Intuitively this seems true to me, but I cannot come up with a proof or counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes in pretty much arbitrary generality.

Let $(\Omega,P)$ be your probability space and note that by abstract change of variables, Fubini and independence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\| X-X'\|^{\kappa}&=\int_{\Omega} \|X-X'\|^{\kappa}\textrm{d}P\\
&=\int_{H^2} \|x-y\|^{\kappa} \textrm{d}(X,X')(P)\\
&=\int_{H}\int_H \|x-y\|^{\kappa}\textrm{d} X(P;x)\textrm{d}X'(P;y)\\
&=\int_H \mathbb{E}\|X-y\|^{\kappa}\textrm{d}X'(P;y)
\end{align}

Hence, if $\mathbb{E}\|X-X'\|^{\kappa}<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}\|X-y\|^{\kappa}<\infty$ for $dX'(P)$-almost every $y$. However, if $X-y\in L^{\kappa}$ for any $y\in H,$ then $X\in L^{\kappa}$. This proves the desired.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @LostStatistician18 You might want to note that we don't need that $X$ and $X'$ follow the same distribution. We're only using that they're independent.